# How to share boost::asio::io_service across plugins [modules]

Tags: c++, c++11, plugins, boost-asio

I would like to implement a single threaded application which also provides a plugin/module API. My application is using a static `io_service` instantiated/initialized in a class method. It might be called a singleton by some. Would it be a good idea to make this available to the plugin implementors?

```
boost::io_service& SomeClass::IOS()
{
  static boost::io_service ios;
  return ios;
}
```

First I thought of allowing the plugins to provide only file descriptors and the application wrapping them as `stream_descriptor` objects but this would prevent the `io_object` specific functionalities provided by boost; this is the reason I thought of providing the static `io_service` to the plugin implementors and restricting them to using `io_object` instances only.

Comment: as long as your api includes the boost asio headers, and the plugins are all compiled using the same #defines, debug levels, ABI etc etc then you'll be fine. In short it'll probably work for you, and fail inexplicably for someone else.

Comment: for this reason I would urge you to consider wrapping the io_service in a public concrete class (e.g. Dispatcher) which exposes `post` and `dispatch` (and maybe even a wrapper around a strand?) in terms of `std::function`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no problem in exposing directly `io_service` as a singleton, if your architecture is based on `boost::asio`.

The issues about ABI are common to every C++ plugin architectue,
and not specific to `boost::asio`.
So, wrapping the `io_service` (as suggested by Richard) is not a solution to this problem, but just a way to hide the decision to use `asio`.

BTW: I guess you want to allow the plugins to manage I/O through `asio`, and the main application dispatch the tasks, so it wouldn't be enough for your wrapper to expose `post` and `dispatch` (useless for the plugins), you should instead provide e.g. sockets and other I/O methods.

Comment: Maybe factory methods for io_object instances would be preferable rather than providing the io_service object as a signleton

Comment: @DaTroop You should use a unique instance of io_service per application, so in this case a factory (whatever kind) is not appropriate. The main app should create the io_service instance and pass it to the plugins. And IMHO in this case there is no real value in writing an interface for the io_service.

Comment: What concerns me is having the io_service exposed. So a factory of io_object instances would prevent misuse of the io_service by plugin developers

Comment: @DaTroop Now I understand: you mean abstract the io_object, not the io_service. Sorry. I see what you mean, but you should also consider wether a pervasive architectural decision like "using boost::asio" can be really hidden and the trade off between the (big) work of defining your own io_object s and expose the io_service. After all: I bet you will never change boost::asio with another async framework...